# stomp.js creating rabbitMQ queue without routing key

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I am using RabbitMQ for pub-sub. I have an exchange of type `topic`, I am subscribing to the exchange using stomp.js

```
var ws = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp')
var client = Stomp.over(ws) 
client.subscribe('/exchange/foo', function() {...})
```

But the problem with a subscription is for every new host, a separate queue is created with a name with a prefix `stomp-subscription-` and an empty routing key. I want to set the routing key as `#`.

Please advise if something is wrong with the above approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) as it looks as though you're not using the correct URL. The docs say the path is `/ws`, not `/stomp`.

To subscribe to a routing key, you must change your code to `/exchange/foo/PATTERN` where PATTERN is the pattern matching the routing key. This is documented in the [STOMP plugin docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d.ed).